# Не обновляется картинка виджета в списке виджетов

Tags: android, виджет

Изначально была другая картинка виджета, далее поменял, а первый удалил, но если зайти в список виджетов, то показывает первую картинку.
В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено, не ошибка в программе, возможно предыдущая картинка сохранена в кеш ОС, которую не понятно как очистить.